# Can JavaScript/TypeScript re-export all named exports under an alias without importing first?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is there any way to do something like the following?

```js
export * as MyAlias from 'path/to/somewhere';
```

I know it's possible to import everything first and then export it, but I would like to be as terse as possible and not need two lines for every re-export.

Specifically I am trying to group related modules together so consumers don't have to know anything about the underlying directory/file structure of the library.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you usage of named exports. It can be used like this:

```
import * as ABC from 'path/to/somewhere';
export { ABC as MyAlias };
```

There is second option that will work as expected:

```
import * as ABC from 'path/to/somewhere';
const MyAlias = ABC;

export default MyAlias;
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment! After seeing your answer I realized that the question was stated too ambiguously. I rewrote it and made it more specific. In your second option the alias doesn't do anything, it's exported as `default`

Comment: Yes, but intellisense will help you include files as MyAlias, instead of ABC