# re-export multiples modules under a single alias in Typescript

Tags: typescript, import, export, alias

I have several files (modules) exporting objects and functions:

```sh
directory/
--> FileA.ts
--> FileB.ts
--> FileC.ts
```

My **goal is to re-export all these functions/objects from all these files under the same alias**. What I would like to do is create a new file `AllClasses.ts` that re-exports everything under the same alias.

**Wrong** example 1 of `./AllFiles.ts`:

```js
export * as AllClasses from 
    './FileA.ts', 
    './FileB.ts',
    './FileC.ts';
```

**Wrong** example 2 of `./AllFiles.ts`:

```js
import * as ClassA from './FileA.ts';
import * as ClassB from './FileB.ts';
import * as ClassC from './FileC.ts';

export {ClassA, ClassB, ClassC} as AllFiles;
```

I have searched on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63841591/can-javascript-typescript-re-export-all-named-exports-under-an-alias-without-imp), [Typescript Handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) or [other websites](https://riptutorial.com/typescript/example/28620/re-export) for a similar way to do that but couldn't find any.

Comment: `export {ClassA, ClassB, ClassC}`

Comment: I already tried both. Actually, when doing that, I can't do something like `let someA = new AllFiles.FileA(...params);`. And I want to be able to do that. I thought to build a AllFile class that contains all the ClassX classes in its parameters but I can't figure out how to do, as attributes must contain instances, not classes...

Comment: You can also directly `export { ClassA } from './FileA.ts';` if that's a named export or `export { default as ClassA } from './FileA.ts';` for the default one

Comment: This still doesn't work. I just tested it. I want all the exports to be under the same alias. Of course I could cheat and put the alias on the import side like `import * as AllFiles from './AllFiles.ts'`. However I want to ensure the alias is always the same, hence I need to enforce the alias name from the export side, namely inside the `./AllFile.ts` file

Comment: You just need to import it after this in the following way `import * as AllFiles from './AllFiles'`. Or you can export it as a namespace `export const AllFiles = {ClassA, ClassB, ClassC}` and then consume as `export { AllFiles } from './AllFiles'` if you need this for whatever reason

Comment: OK, so `export const AllFiles = {ClassA, ClassB, ClassC}` is what you are looking for

Comment: Ok, thanks you very much. This should be the accepted answer. Turns out that it was VSCode error checking that was a bit long. I was able to do `export const AllFiles = {ClassA, ClassB, ClassC}` and then to call it in the import side like `import { AllFiles } from './AllFiles.ts'` and then to use it like so `let A = AllFiles.ClassA.SubClassA(...params);`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This question is 2 years old. The answer was given by Aleksey L.

Export side in `./AllFiles.ts`:

```
AllFiles = {ClassA, ClassB, ClassC}
```

Call it in the import side like so:

```
import { AllFiles } from './AllFiles.ts'
```

And then use it like so:

```
let A = AllFiles.ClassA.SubClassA(...params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an extra file:

AllFiles.ts:

```
import * from './FileA.ts';
import * from './FileB.ts';
import * from './FileC.ts';
```

AllClasses.ts:

```
export * as AllClasses from "./AllFiles.ts";
```

Usage:

```
import { AllClasses } from 'AllClasses.ts'
let x = new AllClasses.ClassA();
```

I could not find a one-file solution for this.